# Families of lines from equation

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

How can it be seen that from the equation of the quadric $Q$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ defined by $x_0x_3=x_1x_2$ that it contains two families of lines and how can one describe them?

Comment: For a parameter $t$, you have a family $x_0=tx_1, x_2=tx_3$ of lines and another family $x_0=tx_2, x_1=tx_3$.

Comment: Why exactly this? How is it you are finding them? Just imposing that it's two equations and that they satisfy the one of the quadric?